# Ghostscript 9.05 unable to convert PDF to PDF using pdfwrite

Tags: ghostscript, ghost4j

I am using Ghostscript version Ghostscript 9.05 and converting PDF to PDF using the following parameters:

`gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf -c .setpdfwrite -f input.pdf`

Exception trace:

`Processing pages 1 through 2.
Page 1
Error: /nocurrentpoint in --run--
Operand stack:
   --dict:14/14(L)--   --dict:0/0(ro)(G)--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1894   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   1877   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1   2   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1155/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:83/200(L)--   --dict:83/200(L)--   --dict:109/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:291/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:24/31(L)--   --dict:6/8(L)--   --dict:28/40(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1`

**Note:** Same file is working perfectly fine in Ghostscript v8.70. The issue is with PDF files generated through `Acrobat Distiller 18.0 (Windows)`

Comment: Without seeing the input file, there is no possible way to offer a suggestion. However you are using a version of Ghostscript which is nearly seven years old. The current version is 9.25 (is 20 versions after the one you are using). You should try the current version.

Comment: GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: ERROR: A pdfmark destination page 5 points beyond the last page 4.

This is the error I am getting while converting. Can't we use v8.70 which is working for us?

Comment: Well you are using a very old version of Ghostscript, the current version is 9.25. You trimmed off the date stamp in the log, but 9.05 is now 6 years old. The first thing to do, as I already said, is try current code. Using code 9 years old instead doesn't seem like a sensible option. You will lose features, many, many bug fixes and introduce security problems (on top of the ones you already have by using such an old version). I've seen this error before and I believe that using a current version will resolve it.